# Which technology is faster text messaging using mobile network or messaging using internet?

Tags: email, sms, social-networking

Which is a faster way to communicate with a large number of people, 'text messages(mass SMS)' or 'via internet(email, social networks)'. Kindly provide a technical evaluation also.

---

If we send messages to multiple people simultaneously using mobile network and via internet, which message will the majority of people receive first?

Comment: Please provide your target group

Comment: lets say we are trying to reach people based on geographic location, i.e a city, state, etc

Comment: The speed of SMS message delivery depends on the carrier. Some carrieres take more time to deliver an SMS message than other carriers.